# Code an app to detect a specific location through input of zipcode?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am trying to develop a component of an app in Android Studio where it allows the user to input their zip code and the app will automatically determine the city and state, instead of having the user type it all in. With this information the app will help connect other users of the app in the same location. I don't want a map to show like a gps. Just have the app be able to recognize the zip codes and specify where the user lives.

Ex: If user typed 90210 and the app would convert it and identify it as Beverly Hills, CA.

If someone could help on how to code this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Is this for the US only? Do you want to store this database internally on the device? or make a query through the internet? Do you want to use the google maps api? or something else? Can you make an hello world application? Do you know how to do an input box and wire it to a submit button? Can you at least code the beginning of this please and post what you've done in your question. We can't give you all the code. That's not what StackOverflow is about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps API to get the information you want.

For Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=94087

Please refer to this page for more documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro